# Debounce vrs Axios Cancel Token which is better

Tags: javascript, axios

I have been using axios cancelToken for sometime when it comes to making api calls, let's say user wants to search for an item, anytime the user types, a request is made and using axios cancel Token, it cancels the previous request and makes a new call each time a user types. But I recently found the debounce function in Javascript which also does similar thing but instead of canceling, it rather delays the request the user makes to the api.. So I want to know when and where to use axios cancel Token and also when to use the debounce function. Which is better?

Comment: You meant `debounce`, right?

Comment: @NickVu yes please

Comment: i would prefer debounce for search, as it won't let initiate fetch request until certain window of time is passed, whereas only cancelling the fetch request with axios cancelToken might still use plenty resources

Comment: @kritiz I get you

Answer (score 1):

As per the Axios docs in 2023, **cancelToken** is deprecated.

https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation